# Email notification one week before to assigned date

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-activity, workflow-history

I am trying to create a workflow that send an email notification before one week to the task assign date.

I am beginner to workflow, so can anyone help me regarding this to develop a 
logic.

Thanks

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on what list data you have available to use to trigger the email notification.

Assuming you have the 'Task Assign Date' in your list, you can use (SharePoint Designer 2013), the 'Add Time To Date' function and specify a value of '-7' days to 'date' where 'date' is your 'Task Assign Date'.

This creates a new workflow variable date which you can then use in conjunction with the 'Pause until Date' function which suspends WF processing until that date is reached (or immediately if that date has passed).  Once the date is reached an email can be send before the WF continues or pauses again until a time or event occurs, depending on your need.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. I have just added a screen shot above. Can you look on it and tell me where I am doing wrong because it is not working. <br> For testing I choose time -5 mins. I am also confuse between "then email current item" statement, does it have to be second option or not??